# SSRS % Number value positive or minus value to see if its possible to display the word 'increase' or 'decrease' automatically

Tags: reporting-services, expression, percentage

I am using SQL Server Reporting Services 2016, I need some advice on the following statement I have in the top row of a Tablix in SSRS inside a textbox, the stament has a few expression within the text:

---

> The total number of referrals received so far in this reporting period
>   is 1427. This is a -6% «Expr3» when compared to the 1518 received in
>   the same period of the previous reporting year.

In this example I would like «Expr3» to say "Decrease" because -6 is a negative number.

---

«Expr3» ---The issue I have is I need to work out <>, I would like to display either Increase or Decrease based upon the value of «Expr2», if «Expr2» is a positive number then I want this value for «Expr3» to show the word "Increase" and if «Expr2» value is a negative number then I want «Expr3» to show "Decrease".

Below my value behind the other expressions

«Expr1»

```
=Sum(Fields!ID.Value, "01_TotalReferralsInThisPeriod")
```

«Expr2»

```
= ((Code.Divide(
(Sum(Fields!ID.Value, "01_TotalReferralsInThisPeriod"))
,
(
Sum(Fields!ID.Value, "02_TotalReferralsInLastPeriod"))
))-1)*100
```

Is there an expression which can do this for me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your expression for Expr3 should be something like this:

```
=IIf(
    ((Code.Divide(
    (Sum(Fields!ID.Value, "01_TotalReferralsInThisPeriod"))
    ,
    (
    Sum(Fields!ID.Value, "02_TotalReferralsInLastPeriod"))
    ))-1)*100
    >= 0,
    "Increase",
    "Decrease"
)
```

This expression assumes that you want to include 0% as an increase, that can of course be changed to fit your needs by modifying the >= 0.

If you are going to have the word "increase" or "decrease" after the percentage though, you may want to display the absolute value of the percentage -- this may just be semantics but it would be a little confusing to me to see a "-6% Decrease", as the double negative implies an increase. If you wanted to change that, just wrap Expr2 in the `abs` function like so:

```
=Abs(
    ((Code.Divide(
    (Sum(Fields!ID.Value, "01_TotalReferralsInThisPeriod"))
    ,
    (
    Sum(Fields!ID.Value, "02_TotalReferralsInLastPeriod"))
    ))-1)*100
)
```

Comment: Thanks, i also need the above to say if either of or both "01_TotalReferralsInThisPeriod" and "02_TotalReferralsInLastPeriod" are 0 then dont add in Increase or Decrease at all.

Comment: Is there an else I could add to the below to say this?

 =Abs(
    ((Code.Divide(
    (Sum(Fields!ID.Value, "01_TotalReferralsInThisPeriod"))
    ,
    (
    Sum(Fields!ID.Value, "02_TotalReferralsInLastPeriod"))
    ))-1)*100
)

Comment: Sorry ignore the above recent posts, I am trying to say this:

Comment: Thanks I am using the code below:
=IIf(
    ((Code.Divide(
    (Sum(Fields!ID.Value, "New01_TotalReferralsInThisPeriod"))
    ,
    (
    Sum(Fields!ID.Value, "New02_TotalReferralsInLastPeriod"))
    ))-1)*100
    >= 0,
    "increase",
    "decrease"
)


And it is working fine, 
But I also need the above to say if either of or both "

New01_TotalReferralsInThisPeriod
" and "

New02_TotalReferralsInLastPeriod
" are 0 value then dont add in Increase or Decrease at all.

Comment: Is there an 'else' I could add to the below to say this?

=IIf(
    ((Code.Divide(
    (Sum(Fields!ID.Value, "New01_TotalReferralsInThisPeriod"))
    ,
    (
    Sum(Fields!ID.Value, "New02_TotalReferralsInLastPeriod"))
    ))-1)*100
    >= 0,
    "increase",
    "decrease"
)

thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want the text to say when one of those values is 0? Do you want something like `This is a N/A when compared to...`, or do you want to change _all_ of the text entirely so that the sentence makes sense?

Comment: Hi,
What I am after is, I would like the wording 'increase' and 'decrease' not to display at all if either of the values for either of the following "New01_TotalReferralsInThisPeriod " and " New02_TotalReferralsInLastPeriod " are 0 value, thanks